# performing mathematical operations for each row of a 2d array against another 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I can only use the numpy import.
I need to calculate the closest distance is the test set to the training set. I.E find the closest distance in the the test(find the distance between all the lists in training array) and return both the test name and training name. The following formula is used:

```
dist(x,y)=√((a-a2 )^2+(b-b2 )^2+(c-c2 )^2+(d-d2)^2 )
```

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12gaqBy5Xjs3ah7IZ1VZT1TEsU2dajzRO) to data used and expect first row.

This is the code I have that functions correctly for the first row in the Train test set. I need for each row of the train array to go through the same operation in variable q.
Below is my input

```
Training
a   b   c   d   name training
5   3   1.6 0.2 G
5   3.4 1.6 0.4 G
5.5 2.4 3.7 1   R
5.8 2.7 3.9 1.2 R
7.2 3.2 6   1.8 Y
6.2 2.8 4.8 1.8 Y

testing
a2  b2  c2  d2  name true
5   3.6 1.4 0.2 E
5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 G
6.9 3.1 4.9 1.5 R
5.5 2.3 4   1.3 R
6.4 2.7 5.3 1.9 Y
6.8 3   5.5 2.1 Y
```

```
train = np.asarray(train)
test = np.asarray(test)
print('Train shape',train.shape)
print('test shape',test.shape)

train_1 = train[:,0:(train.shape[1])-1].astype(float)
test_1 = test[:,0:(test.shape[1])-1].astype(float)
print('Train '+'\n',train_1)
print('test '+'\`enter code here`n',test_1)
q=min((np.sqrt(np.sum((train_1[0,:]-test_1)**2,axis=1,keepdims=True))))
```

I expect to get the closest distance from the training row compared to entire array of test. Using this the first row train using the formula would produce the below. I would then return G,E as those are the 2 rows that are closest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html). here is an example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.linalg.norm(arr)
5.477225575051661
```

`5.477225575051661` is the result of `sqrt(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2)`

```py
import numpy as np

train = np.array([[5, 3, 1.6, 0.2],
                  [5, 3.4, 1.6, 0.4],
                  [5.5, 2.4, 3.7, 1],
                  [5.8, 2.7, 3.9, 1.2],
                  [7.2, 3.2, 6, 1.8],
                  [6.2, 2.8, 4.8, 1.8]])

test = np.array([[5, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
                 [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
                 [6.9, 3.1, 4.9, 1.5],
                 [5.5, 2.3, 4, 1.3],
                 [6.4, 2.7, 5.3, 1.9],
                 [6.8, 3, 5.5, 2.1]])

# first get subtraction of each row of train to test
subtraction = train[:, None, :] - test[None, :, :]
# get distance from each train_row to test
s = np.linalg.norm(subtraction, axis=2, keepdims=True)
print(np.min(s, axis=1))
# get minimum
q = np.argmin(s, axis=1)
print("minimum indices:")
print(q)
```

output:

```
[[0.63245553]
 [0.34641016]
 [0.43588989]
 [0.51961524]
 [0.73484692]
 [0.55677644]]
minimum indices:
[[0]
 [0]
 [3]
 [3]
 [5]
 [4]]
```

Comment: This is actually only finding the distance between the corresponding rows. row 1 of test and train, row 2 of test and train, etc. I want each row train to subtract from every row of test and the distance of those subarrays would the the minimum. So row 1 of train will create be subtracted from all 6 rows of test then the formula is applied to those to find the smallest distance. I would then perform this for row 2 of train against all 6 rows of test and so on.

Comment: @user11861166 i have edited my answer, check whether it's okay

Comment: Yes this has resolved the first portion of my question, the second portion was to print the row indexes that were used to get the minimum distance. 0.63245553 uses rows 1 from both train and test, while 0.34641016 uses row 2 of train and row 1 of testing.

Comment: @user11861166 sorry for not reading carefully, i updated it again.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this. For the Indices I would like the indices of the original array used that are closest. I.E. 0.63245553(Train-0,Test-0), 0.34641016(Train-1,Test-0), etc.

Comment: @user11861166 on my `q`, its indices are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` which are train_row_numbers and its values are `0, 0, 3, 3, 5, 4`, which are corresponding test_row_numbers. so from output `q`:
train_row_1 is best fit test_row_1,
train_row_2 is best fit test_row_1,
train_row_3 is best fit test_row_4, 
train_row_4 is best fit test_row_4, 
train_row_5 is best fit test_row_6, 
train_row_6 is best fit test_row_5